# increment csv file number after loop completion

Tags: python, loops, csv, iteration

I am executing a loop and save data in a csv file. to store the data i am creating a path and directory and append the csv file. as it is the code executes fine and generates one csv file upon completion. i would like the csv file to increment each time i run the code so i dont have to delete or overwrite the previous one such a way that i get file_0 for run1, file_1 for run 2 and so on. i inserted `# fileName = "{}/{}_{}.csv".format(file_path[0], self.file_name, file_path[1])'' but this saves me each point in a separate file. any suggestions welcome. thanks.

```
import csv
from fileinput import filename
from locale import currency
import time
from numpy import append, outer
import time
from datetime import datetime
import os
from random import random

#create folder timestamped
class CreateFile():
    def __init__(self, procedure):
        self.procedure = procedure  # Get the procedure name.
        self.createfile()           # Call create file function.

    def createfile(self):
        date = datetime.now().date()     
        PARENT_DIR = "C:\test/".format(date)   # Get the path.
        DIR = '{}'.format(self.procedure)                                   # Get procedure name.
        self.PATH = os.path.join(PARENT_DIR, DIR)                           # Form a full path.
        try:
            if not os.path.exists(self.PATH):                               # If the given path does not exists.
                os.makedirs(self.PATH)                                      # Make a directory.
        except OSError:                                                     # OSError occur, don't make the directory.
            print ("Creation of the directory [%s] failed." % DIR)          # Print message.
        else:                                                               # Successfully created the director, print the message.
            print ("Successfully created the directory %s " % DIR)

    def get_file(self):
        file_list = os.listdir(self.PATH)   # Load path into list directory.
        file_count = len(file_list)         # Chech the number of file(s) under the given path.
        return [self.PATH, file_count]      # Return full path and file count under this folder.

# initialization and setpoints list
startpoint = 300
setpoint = 310
step = 10  
temp_list = []
for x in range(startpoint, setpoint+1, step):
    temp_list.append(x)
print(temp_list)

class save_data1():
    def __init__(self, file_name):
        self.file_name = file_name
        file_path_count = CreateFile(file_name).get_file()
        self.fileName = "{}/{}.csv".format(file_path_count[0], file_name)
     
    def record_csv(self, fileName, now, ep1):
        with open(fileName, 'a', newline='') as csvfile:
            header = ["Timestamp",'Temp', "ep1"]
            writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=header)
            if csvfile.tell() == 0:
                writer.writeheader()
            writer.writerow(
                {
                    "Timestamp": now,
                    'Temp': temp,
                    "ep1": ep1
                }
            )
        csvfile.close()

    def test(self):
        file_path = CreateFile(self.file_name).get_file()
        # fileName = "{}/{}_{}.csv".format(file_path[0], self.file_name, file_path[1])
        fileName = "{}/{}.csv".format(file_path[0], self.file_name)
        now = datetime.now()
        ep1 = random()   #here just random number instead of instrument
        self.record_csv(fileName, now, ep1)

# Set setpoint in Temp list
for temp in temp_list:
# print a header
    print('')
    hdr = '______ T ______     __________ H __________\t______ Ext Param ______'
    print(hdr)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print('setpoint:', temp) 
    if temp == 300:
        save_data1('meas1').test()
    else:
        print('Waiting ')
        save_data1('meas1').test()
```

Comment: "i would like the csv file to increment each time i run the code" This sounds like you need to figure out a way to find the numerical suffix of the file created on the previous run.

Comment: indeed, but if i execute the test() method several time in the loop (in the MWE 2 times) then it keeps creating me a 2 files with 1point in each. i need to have 1 file per loop completion.

Comment: Then creating the file belongs outside the loop.

Comment: Side note: keep things as simple as you can. You seem to be using classes where they aren't necessary. I suggest just making top-level functions to perform tasks such as `create_file()` and `save_data()` rather than making these classes. Remember that functions are **actions** in your code whereas classes are **things**.

Comment: i thought that would make the code cleaner and simpler to read as i will have a few more actions related to several instruments for each i ll have to save a csv file.

Comment: Classes are in fact a great way to make code cleaner. One thing to keep in mind: classes are **things** that actions can be applied to. This means that a class name is usually a noun. However, `CreateFile` is a verb, an action, not a thing. In your case, it might make sense to have an `Instrument` class with a `create_file()` method. In the context of your current question, though, this doesn't seem necessary yet and can be something you look at adding in the future.

Comment: In your current question, I suggest simplifying to global methods `create_file()` and `save_data()`. This will help you think more clearly about the actions you are performing. As you see related data that represents objects in your program, you can figure out how to create classes to represent those objects.

Comment: Doing this will help you figure out your current problem as well. If I were working on this, I would first figure out how to create one file each time I run the program. I wouldn't worry about avoiding overwriting that file yet. Adding a number suffix can be added later.

Comment: that MWE does that, i get a file with my 2 random points in it then if i run again the code i get 2 more lines in the same file. i want to generate a new file instead for these 2 new lines.  as you say i should avoid saving Creatfile in the test() but i am stuck.

Comment: Ok, I understand better now. You say "i inserted <some code> but this saves me each point in a separate file" Where did you insert this line of code? Do you mean the place where you have it commented in `test()`? I don't understand how that change can make your program go from saving every point in the same file to saving each point in a separate file. I think at this point, you need to debug your code to see what is going on. To start, check out [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for some tips.

Comment: yes correct. i am trying to debug. thanks